# Using range::find on a view

Tags: c++, range-v3

I'd like to rangify the following code, which checks for the first occurance of a sequence of unique characters:

```
bool hasOnlyUniqueElements( auto& data ) {
    std::unordered_set<char> set;

    for( auto& value : data )
        set.emplace( value );

    return set.size() == data.size();
}

int64_t getStartPacketMarker( const std::string& data, int64_t markerSize ) {
    for( int64_t i = 0; i < data.size() - markerSize; i++ )
    {
        std::string_view packet( data.begin() + i, data.begin() + i + markerSize );
        if( hasOnlyUniqueElements( packet ) )
            return i + markerSize;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I came up with the following, that uses ranges but is only marginally better:

```
int64_t getStartPacketMarker( const std::string& data, int64_t markerSize ) {
    int64_t idx = 0;
    for( auto packet :  data | ranges::views::sliding( markerSize ) ) {
        if( hasOnlyUniqueElements( packet ) )
            return idx + markerSize;
        idx++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This should be a simple find operation, but I couldn't make it work and couldn't find any examples on find being used on views. Is it possible to use find on views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `find` on views. However, in your case, you should use `find_if` since you are checking against a predicate function:

```cpp
auto view = data | std::views::slide(markerSize);
auto it = std::ranges::find_if(
              view, somePredicate
          );
return it == view.end() ? -1 : it - view.begin();
```

However, since your predicate function has an `auto`-deduced parameter, you can't get the function pointer of it directly, and you would need to wrap it in a lambda instead:

```cpp
auto view = data | std::views::slide(markerSize);
auto it = std::ranges::find_if(
              view, [](const auto& v) { return hasOnlyUniqueElements(v); }
          );
return it == view.end() ? -1 : it - view.begin();
```

Comment: @Grimkin I'm not that familiar with range-v3, but I assume it should work with both.

Comment: I now tried it now and it works in both. My mistake was to trust Intellisense in MSVC which showed an error and I didn't try to compile it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `std::ranges::find_if` on the range you could skip the ´for´ loop that builds the set in `hasOnlyUniqueElements` using `std::unique`:

```
auto set = data;
std::unique(std::sort(set));
```

Comment: Note, `unique` is an algorithm, so you would need to call it as `unique(data)`. Also `unique` requires the duplicates to be consecutive to work.

Comment: You are absolutely correct on both counts. I'll edit the answer